# beamer overlays and table rules

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

I am trying to use `\only{...}` within a table to selectively add blocks of lines. This works as long as I don't have a `\midrule` or `\bottomrule` included or following the part contained in `\only{...}`.

Why does this happen and is there a way to achieve this nevertheless?

An example follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Example}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
        bla & bla \\
      \midrule
        A & A \\
        B & B \\  
        \only<1>{%
          \midrule  
            C & C \\
            D & D \\ }
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \only<2>{Something else}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with some carefully placed comments, see below for example. It seems that LaTeX doesn't like it when you place `\\` and `\*rule` on different lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Example}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
        bla & bla \\
      \midrule
        A & A \\
        B & B %  
        \only<1>{%
          \\\midrule  
          C & C %
        }%
        \only<2>%
        {%
        \\
        D & D  %
        }%
      \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks very strange, though...

Comment: LaTeX does not care whether `\\ ` and `\*rule` are on the same line or not. The linebreak is nothing else than a space token. The problem is the `\only` in between. See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500100/120953) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `! Misplaced \noalign` because, after full expansion, there may be no remaining tokens between the TeX primitives `\cr`, which is used in `\\`, and `\noalign`, which is used in the `\*rule` macros.
Tokens that disappear during the expansion, like `\if`, are fine.
But `\only` cannot be fully expandable because it needs to keep track of how many overlays there are on this slide.
Therefore it cannot be used between `\\` and `\*rule`.
(Same goes for `\multicolumn`, by the way).

I would not use `\only` because it places nothing instead on those overlays where the argument is hidden, causing the content of the frame to jump around.
Instead I would use `\uncover`, which behaves like `\visible` by default. This means that the argument is not visible on not matching overlays, but there is space reserved as much as there would be needed, if the argument was actually placed there.
This avoids undesired jumping.
If you want a different behaviour later on you can easily change it with `\setbeamercovered`, e.g. setting it to `transparent`.
But of course, this changes nothing about the problem at hand.

`\only` and `\uncover` are both special cases of the `\alt` command which places the first argument on matching overlays and the second argument on not matching overlays.
I have implemented a simplified, fully expandable version of `\alt`.
Because it can not keep track of the overlays, the exising overlays must be declared separately—either at the beginning of the frame with `\begin{frame}<-5>` or by a usual overlayaware command like `\only`. I have used this `\xalt` to define an overlayaware version of the `\*rule` macros.

I have not reimplemented the full power of overlay specifications but only the most important ones:

- `<n>` a single overlay
- `<n-m>` a range of overlays
- `<n->` all overlays ≥ n
- `<-m>` all overlays ≤ m
- `<*>` all overlays

The lookahead whether there is an optional overlay specification given after the `\*rule` macros is not quite as safe as usual, because it needs to be fully expandable.
Therefore you should make sure that there is no `{` following one of my redefined `\*rule` macros.
But I cannot think of any situation where it would make much sense to start a cell with a `{`, anyway.

I have taken the information how much space I need to insert instead of a `\*rule` macro from the [booktabs documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) section 7 *Technical summary of commands*.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{booktabs}


% ------- \xalt -------

\makeatletter

\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}

\def\xalt<#1>{%
    \if *#1%
        % matches any overlay
        \expandafter \@secondofthree
    \else
        % continue overlay check
        \expandafter \@firstofone
    \fi
        {\@xalt@checkrange<#1->}%
}

\def\@xalt@checkrange<#1-#2>{%
    \ifx \relax#2\relax
        % is not a range
        \expandafter \@firstoftwo
    \else
        % is a range
        \expandafter \@secondoftwo
    \fi
        {\@xalt@checknumber<#1>}%
        {\@xalt@checklower<#1-#2>}%
}

\def\@xalt@checknumber<#1>{%
    \ifnum \beamer@slideinframe=#1
        % overlay is matched
        \expandafter \@firstoftwo
    \else
        % overlay is *not* matched
        \expandafter \@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\def\@xalt@checklower<#1-#2>{%
    \ifx \relax#1\relax
        % lower bound not given => match
        \expandafter \@firstofone
    \else \ifnum \beamer@slideinframe<#1
        % overlay is *not* matched
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \@thirdofthree
    \else
        % lower bound is matched 
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \@firstofone
    \fi \fi
        {\@xalt@checkupper<-#2>}%
}

% #2 ends with an additional -

\def\@xalt@checkupper<-#1->{%
    \ifx \relax#1\relax
        % upper bound not given => match
        \expandafter \@firstoftwo
    \else \ifnum \beamer@slideinframe>#1
        % overlay is *not* matched
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \@secondoftwo
    \else
        % upper bound is matched 
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \@firstoftwo
    \fi \fi
}

\makeatother


% ------- \toprule -------

\let\originaltoprule=\toprule

\def\overlayawaretoprule<#1>{%
    \xalt<#1>%
        {\toprule}%
        {\addlinespace[\dimexpr \abovetopsep + \heavyrulewidth + \belowrulesep \relax]}%
}

\renewcommand{\toprule}[1]{%
    \ifx <#1%
        \expandafter \overlayawaretoprule
    \else
        \expandafter \originaltoprule
    \fi
    #1%
}

% ------- \midrule -------

\let\originalmidrule=\midrule

\def\overlayawaremidrule<#1>{%
    \xalt<#1>%
        {\midrule}%
        {\addlinespace[\dimexpr \aboverulesep + \lightrulewidth + \belowrulesep \relax]}%
}

\renewcommand{\midrule}[1]{%
    \ifx <#1%
        \expandafter \overlayawaremidrule
    \else
        \expandafter \originalmidrule
    \fi
    #1%
}


% ------- \bottomrule -------

\let\originalbottomrule=\bottomrule

\def\overlayawarebottomrule<#1>{%
    \xalt<#1>%
        {\bottomrule}%
        {\addlinespace[\dimexpr \aboverulesep + \heavyrulewidth + \belowbottomsep \relax]}%
}

\renewcommand{\bottomrule}[1]{%
    \ifx <#1%
        \expandafter \overlayawarebottomrule
    \else
        \expandafter \originalbottomrule
    \fi
    #1%
}


% ------- test document -------

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
            bla & bla \\
        \midrule
            A & A \\
            B & B \\
        \midrule<2->
            \uncover<2->{C & C} \\
            \uncover<2->{D & D} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \uncover<3->{Something else}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want the behaviour of an `\only` you can simply leave the second argument of `\xalt` empty:

```
\def\xonly<#1>#2{\xalt<#1>{#2}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
            bla & bla \\
        \midrule
            A & A \\
            B & B \\
        \xonly<2->{\midrule}
            \xonly<2->{C & C \\}
            \xonly<2->{D & D \\}
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \only<3->{Something else}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens but here's a heavy-handed solution: write your tabular environment twice inside different `\only` statements.

```
\begin{frame}{Example}
 \only<1>{\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
      bla & bla \\
    \midrule
      A & A \\
      B & B \\
        \midrule
          C & C \\
          D & D \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \only<2->{\begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
        bla & bla \\
      \midrule
        A & A \\
        B & B \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \only<2>{Something else}
\end{frame}
```